# Getting Data from Express POST Request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, sendgrid

I am attempting to try to console.log data that I am sending to my server via a POST request.  Here is the code:

Front End:

```
    onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.name || !this.state.email || !this.state.message) {
        this.setState(() => ({ error: 'Please fill out all the above fields!' }));
    } else {
        this.setState(() => ({ error: '' }));

        fetch('/contact', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                message: this.state.message
            })
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((response) => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
            .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

}
```

Back-End

```
app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body);
   sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
   const msg = {
      to: 'email',
      from: 'email',
      subject: 'New Message From Portfolio',
      text: 'test',
      html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with 
              Node.js</strong>',
   };
   sgMail.send(msg)
   .then(() => {
     console.log("email send successful");
   })
})
```

I am using sendGrid to send the email.  The sendGrid code is successful, as I am getting the email.  I thought by putting it in JSON form on the fetch request it was in a form my server could recognize.  But my logic on that may be wrong.  On the console.log on the server side code I am getting "undefined".

Comment: Have you set up `body-parser`?

Comment: Hey Colin.... I just attempted to set it up, but I must have put the wrong configuration in my server.js file because it broke it... looking at the docs now to make sure I am up to date with how to set it up on this version of node/express.

Comment: I just had the wrong configuration unfortunately.  Needed to update it cause I am using new versions.  I am still getting a net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in the console after about 4 minutes after send.  It does not prevent the send but would rather not have it.  It that just because I am not sending any data back to the UI?

Comment: Can you post your `server.js` or `index.js` where you set it up?

Comment: The above back-end code is all I think is needed to see.  From the feedback I have read it is just because I don't have a res.send or res action going back to the frontend.